# Firefox expands select size when appending content

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, append

I'm currently working on a script that loads dynamic content (fetched via Ajax) into a `select`. Since I am getting multiple elements, my code currently looks something like this

```
$.each(data, function(key,val) {
    $("#myselect").append(
        $("<option></option>").val(key).html(val)
    );
});
```

Now this works fine. And when I tested it in Chrome, I saw nothing wrong. But then I looked again in Firefox and FF seems to expand the set size when appending content.

in **Chrome**

[image]

in **Firefox**

[image]

Or if you want to see for yourself, [I have created a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GG4wS/1/).

My question now obviously is, what is causing this behaviour and how can I suppress it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a height to the select-element solved the problem.

```
select {
    height: 80px;
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VY9s3/1/)

If you remove the `padding` from the `option`-elements it works without resizing. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VY9s3/3/)

Comment: Thanks but is there another way? With the height fixed the elements won't fill properly (with your example you can scroll for like 2px in FF)

Comment: If you remove the padding from the option-elements it works without resizing. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VY9s3/3/)

Comment: That is only because there are too few elements to reach the end - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VY9s3/4/) ;)

Comment: @kingkero Micha is correct. Remove the padding and it works fine. The only reason Chrome is working differently is because the padding is not being applied

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thank you .. Especially thank you @MichaB, I fell so dumb for not correctly reading your comment/the fiddle. `margin` seems to work fine though